# wpf application for broadcasting video with delay

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I have a wpf application for broadcasting video using expression encoder 4 and framework 4.0, but i got a delay of 15 sec while broadcasting.Is there any suggestion to reduce the delay while broadcasting.

below is the Code

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                EncoderDevice video = null;
                EncoderDevice audio = null;

```
            GetSelectedVideoAndAudioDevices(out video, out audio);
            StopJob();

            if (video == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            StopJob();
            _job = new LiveJob();
            if (video != null && audio != null)
            {
                //StopJob();
                _deviceSource = null;

                _deviceSource = _job.AddDeviceSource(video, audio);
                _job.ActivateSource(_deviceSource);

                // Finds and applys a smooth streaming preset        
                //_job.ApplyPreset(LivePresets.VC1HighSpeedBroadband4x3);

                // Creates the publishing format for the job
                PullBroadcastPublishFormat format = new PullBroadcastPublishFormat();
                format.BroadcastPort = 9090;
                format.MaximumNumberOfConnections = 50;

                // Adds the publishing format to the job
                _job.PublishFormats.Add(format);

                // Starts encoding
                _job.StartEncoding();
            }
            //webCamCtrl.StartCapture();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLogFile(this.GetType().Name, "button1_Click", ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: It would be good to describe a bit more. How do you do the broadcasting? What might be the problem? What did you do so far to analyse the problem?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder to play the video.        using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Live;
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder;